# HTML and js with option value usage

Tags: javascript, html

I have first a  with 3 option value in it. When I select one of the values, I want it to remember which one I picked and once I press my button the javascript will open a specific url.

Some code sample.

```
       <select id="dd-files">
        <option value="asdf">Pick:</option>
        <option value="url1">File1</option>
        <option value="url2">File2</option>
        <option value="url3">File3</option>
       </select>
      </section>
    </div>
<br>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-primary get-data" href="#">Button</a>
        </div>
```

**javascript** This javascript directily just to know how it all works, so I just tested it.

```
$(".get-data").on("click",function() {
  var location = 'http://hardcodedurl.com';
  window.open(location);
```

Then I have another function, which when I pick one option value, stores it and open it directly, but instead of open it directly, I would like my second script just to open when my button ".get-data" is pressed.

```
$(function () {
  $('#dd-files').on('change', function() {
    debugger;
    var url = $(this).val();
    if (url) {
      window.location = url;
    }
    return false;
  })
})
```

Any advice for a newbie?

Comment: Do they call you the HTML Slasher?

Comment: The html \ is because its written in js, so for it to read next line, im using \ otherwise it crashes you know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear why do you need `on('change')` event. To make it open when button is pressed, you just need something like this:

```
$(".get-data").on("click",function() {
  var location = $('#dd-files').val(); 
  if(location) {
     window.open(location);
  }
}
```

Just take an url from `#dd-files` directly.

Comment: Oh thank you! That worked just fine, dont ask me what I was thinking there for a second. By the way, if this is placed in a form, which is generated by pressing a <li> children one step ahead.

Like this
<li><a id='stoparea' data-name='data-value' href='#'>firstpicked</a></li>"

Is it possible to have it look on first which option I picked one step ahead and then store next one?

Comment: Frankly speaking it is not clear to me what are you talking about. Once you have few elements - just build a selector which will get an element you need, take its value and do whatever you need with it.